# Can SQL Server query time-complexity (latency) reach O(1) given a set of optimizations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-complexity

Imagine one has two SQL tables containing daily time-series data.

Both of the tables have primary key (and since it's SQL Server the key is also clustered). The key is composite and includes field  `BUSINESS_DATE` of type `Date`.

Both table are partitioned monthly.

`Table_Short` contains only 2 years worth of data.
`Table_Long` contains 50 years worth of data.

The end-user can only query maximum **last** 1 year worth of data at a time. Therefore, the front-end (UI) will always make a `SELECT` statement like

```
SELECT <some columns>
FROM <Table>
WHERE BUSINESS_DATE >= t1 
AND BUSINESS_DATE <= t2
```

for some dates `t1`, `t2`.

Given that the user only needs to look into the **last** year and the fact that the tables are partitioned and ordered by `business_date`, is it true, that the query latency should **not** depend on the table size, thus query against Table_Long will take the same time as against Table_Long?

My understanding was that SQL Server stores tables as Binary Tree, where search is at worst `O(log n)`.
However, given that we only need the *last* year in either 2 years or 50 years, should the time-complexity become `O(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query latencies may still depend on table size even though SQL Server uses a B-tree index to efficiently search and retrieve data. In certain cases, latency can depend on table size even if the data is partitioned.

In theory, while time complexity of the search operation may still be O(log n). When it comes to practice, `SELECT` statement shouldn't depend on the overall size of the tables, but more on the number of partitions that need to be scanned to get data within a specific date range.(the partitioning scheme allows for efficient pruning of irrelevant data)

- In your case, we are querying for the last year of data, and both tables are partitioned by month. SQL Server query optimizer should be able to use the partitioning scheme to prune the partitions that do not contain the relevant data, resulting in a smaller search space and faster query execution.

Ps. SQL Server uses a clustered index physically ordering the data in a table, which further improves query performance.

- in your case, the primary key in both tables is clustered and includes `BUSINESS_DATE` field (data within each partition will be ordered by `BUSINESS_DATE`, making it easier and faster to locate data within each partition, resulting in query execution times that are not dependent on the overall size of the tables)

Comment: Latency (per row) isn't going to go up by much if the size of the data being read is the same, until you literally get into billions of rows, where the B+ tree starts getting more levels. The fanout in the tree is very high. Good answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a table using a clustered index with business_date as the leading key column and you also partition the table by month, the query optimizer can consider plans that only look at the partitions that can qualify for a given time range.  You've described an example with fixed times, and the optimizer does consider static partition elimination.  It also supports dynamic partition elimination if you are passing in parameters instead.  You can look at the output plan to see if it has done either of these things if you'd like.

However, it is incorrect to simply map this to O(N log N) vs. O(1).  Internally, if the static partition elimination plan is picked, it likely still does an index range on the remaining partitions.  Internally to that, each of them are actually separate physical b-trees.  So, you can think of this as "seek to the first row for each b-tree and then scan the pages linearly" which is 1 log N search per b-tree (12 in your case) plus an O(N) scan where N is each partition's set of rows.  It is obviously faster, but there are details that make simple big-O analysis not a perfect metric to consider this - once you add a join or a group by, things get more complicated as well.  I hope that helps give a better understanding of what is happening.